# Override Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using nav pills from Twitter-Bootstrap. At certain screen resolutions, the pills are pushed down for no apparent reason. When using Firebug, if I eliminate the display:table from the .nav-pills, the problem goes away. I have tried to override the display:table in one of my own .css files, but so far Firefox always views my override attempt as a separate style.

Here is an example of the problem. I know this is not the best way to handle the problem, but it looks like the best way to demonstrate the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Bootstrap CSS:

```
.nav-tabs:before, .nav-pills:before, .nav-tabs:after, .nav-pills:after 
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

My CSS:

```
.nav-tabs:before, .nav-pills:before, .nav-tabs:after, .nav-pills:after 
{
    display:block !important;   
}
```

CSS results:
Firefox appears to recognize both css statements as separate styles, when my display style should override the bootstrap style.

[image: Firefox CSS results]

Comment: *"Firefox always views my override attempt as a separate style"* What does that mean? Specifically, how does it view it as a separate style?

Comment: @Cody Gray: If you look at the actual css selector, they are identical. The display:table in the bootstrap.css should be crossed out, because the display:block !important in Site.css has overriding it. The only reason why I used !important is to make sure my style would override bootstrap's style. Since this did not happen, this makes me think Firefox views both blocks as targeting different blocks of HTML.

Comment: Did you try loading your css before twitter bootstrap css?

Comment: Having same problem. Also seeing it in Chrome. In Chrome, using the dec-css inspector to disable the 'display' rule isn't enough; the 'content' rule needs to go. Trying to override in normal ways isn't working: my override rules *don't* show in Firebug/Chrome-inspector,  *don*t* have desired effect when setting 'display' to 'none' or 'content' to 'none' or 'normal'. But they clearly are being seen, because if I set content to an actual string, it appears. Very odd. Would love to have a real answer; for now I'm editting Bootstrap.css to remove this bit of unexplained problematic black magic.

Comment: Try to write in Mediaquery, or cange it in bootstap.css

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your element in Chrome, you can see if a css selector, applied to that element belongs to a media query.

When you configured your bootstrap download, did you check the options in the Responsive section?

I guess that the problem is that a css selector from a media query is overriding your own css-selector.